# Don't show UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm trying to use `UICollectionViewController` on Xcode 6, but i can't see custom cell or prototype items. I put Label in cell with white color, I implemented numberOfSections and numberOfItemsInSection but problem persists. Can help me? Thanks in advance.

```
@implementation CollectionViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 5;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to set some data at : `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Small example of my code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MEMediaView *cell =  [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MEMediaView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell awakeFromNib];
    [cell setMemryMediaData:[mediaArray_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell setMediaContent];
    if (shadow)
    {
        [cell shadeCoverImage];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Also do not forget to set delegates :

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: I edit my unswear please try

Comment: I Have this on Connection Inspector, i don't know why have this problem, UITableViewController it's ok, but UICollectionViewController i show black screen, i change background color with prototype cell but the problem persists.

Comment: Solution is remove [self.collectionview registerClass:[NewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

in storybord we dont need this.